# Import flat file to SQL server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, file-import

I want to make a program in C# that imports two types of files to SQL Server: tab delimited and fixed columns. Actually, I need to download a file every day and import that file into my database. I could make a console app with batch script. I saw some examples like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Cs_CSV_import_export.aspx), but I don´t know if it is the best object-oriented way to do it.

I could use `StreamReader`, `Regex` and so on, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

PS:
In VBA I used "QueryTables.Add".

Comment: Could you show the format for what the file is supposed to look like related to the SQL server?

Comment: Please note that Batch tag is "used for Windows batch file questions". Don't use it just because your question is related to "batch" word in any way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, then you should look at the native tools that SQL Server provides for this, namely [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx). [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/67409) is a list of FAQs about bcp.

Answer (score 2):

You can import in fully managed code via [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx); all you need to do is pass SqlBulkCopy an IDataReader that handles TSV. Fortunately the [FastCsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) on codeproject can do exactly that.

Comment: I have some trash rows in my file. I need something like row patterns (Regex). I could create some file converter then use SQLBulk

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect job for SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). You can easily define a data import task in SSIS and then schedule it to run by using a SQL job.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 express

Answer (score 0):

```
bulk insert [dbo].[CoursesTemp]
```

from 'C:\Users\Public\Downloads\Courses.csv'

```
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n')
go
insert [dbo].[Courses]
  (code, description, instructor, date, venue, duration)
select 
   code, description, instructor, cast(date as date), venue,
   duration
from [dbo].[CoursesTemp]
```